# what the alternative to native libmedia in Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-ndk

i am using native code that uses libmedia.so and it was running fine in android 2.2 but when i tried it in 2.3.3 it got this error :

```
09-28 16:06:28.206: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3307): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1316]:  1239 cannot locate '_ZN7android11AudioRecordC1EijijijPFviPvS1_ES1_i'...
```

What is the alternative to AudioRecord/libmedia in 2.3  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this in the changelog in android_nds_r5

this API only works with 2.3 and above

Audio APIs based on the OpenSL ES standard that support playback and recording as well as control over platform audio effects

Comment: Hello mozarty, I am facing similar problem for unsatisfied link error, to as a workaround i used AudioTrack in JAVA, but after few track played it is getting crashed, Do you have any idea or faced similar problem, crash log says it crashed from libmedia.so file.